# What arguments are there in favor of weak typing?

Tags: type-systems, type-safety, weak-typing

This came up in a discussion with a friend, and I found myself hard-pressed to think up an any good arguments.  What benefits do weak typing confer?

Comment: Cooper and Torczon's [Engineering a Compiler](http://www.amazon.com/Engineering-Compiler-Keith-Cooper/dp/155860698X/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1295472754&sr=1-1) defines weak typing as employing a poorly designed type system. That sure doesn't sound like it would benefit anyone.

Comment: @Corbin March: Nice one. I need to add that to my list.

Comment: The best argument can be given by corporate executives: _it allows me to hire cheap people to build my systems_

Answer (score 50):

The problem with this kind of discussion is simply that the terms "weak typing" and "strong typing" are undefined, unlike for example the terms "static typing", "dynamic typing", "explicit typing", "implicit typing", "duck typing", "structural typing" or "nominal typing". Heck, even the terms "manifest typing" and "latent typing", which are still open areas of research and discussion are probably better defined.

So, until your friend provides a definition of the term "weak typing" that is stable enough to serve as the basis of a discussion, it doesn't even make sense to answer this question.

Unfortunately, apart from [Nick's answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/38014/1352), nobody of the answerers bothered to provide their definition either, and you can see the confusion that generates in some of the comments. It's hard to tell, since nobody actually provides their definitions, but I think I count at least three different ones, just on this very page.

Some of the more commonly used definitions are (and yes, I *know* that pretty much none of them makes any sense, but those are the definitions I've seen people actually use):

- weak typing = unsafe typing / strong typing = safe typing
- weak typing = dynamic typing / strong typing = static typing
- weak typing = duck typing / strong typing = nominal typing
- weak typing = structural typing / strong typing = nominal typing
- weak typing = implicit typing / strong typing = explicit typing
- weak typing = latent typing / strong typing = manifest typing
- weak typing = no typing / strong typing = typing
- weak typing = implicit casts / strong typing = only explicit casts
- weak typing = implicit or explicit casts / strong typing = no casts at all
- weak typing = implicit conversions / strong typing = only explicit conversions
- weak typing = implicit or explicit conversions / strong typing = no conversions at all
- weak typing = interpretation / strong typing = compilation
- weak typing = slow / strong typing = fast
- weak typing = garbage collection / strong typing = manual memory management
- weak typing = manual memory management / strong typing = garbage collection
- … and many others

The three definitions that seem to be used *most* widely, however, are

- weak typing = your stupid crappy programming language / strong typing = my super-awesome programming language
- weak typing = every other programming language / strong typing = the only programming language I ever bothered to learn (usually either Java, C# or C++; strangely, people who learn e.g. Haskell or Scheme as their first and only language don't seem to share this worldview)
- weak typing = every language I don't understand / strong typing = Java (substitute with C# or C++ at will)

Unless everybody agrees on a definition of what "weak typing" even *is*, it doesn't even make sense to think about what its advantages might be. Advantages of what? Even worse, if there is no definition *at all*, then everybody can just shift their definitions to fit their arguments, and every discussion is pretty much guaranteed to devolve into a flamewar.

I myself have personally changed my own definition several times over the years and have now reached the point where I don't even consider the terms useful any more. I also used to think that weak typing (in its various definitions) has a place in shell scripting, but whenever I have to solve the same problem in Bash and PowerShell, I am painfully reminded how wrong I was.

Comment: Pretty cynical answer! I get where you're coming from but I feel it's "good enough" to guess that anyone who doesn't provide a definition is referring to "weak and/or dynamic typing", which is why I included both in my answer. I know it's not perfect, but most people seem to tune out when it comes to defining type systems.

Comment: I don't consider wikipedia a perfect source, but it acknowledges the mess in [Strong Typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_typing): "Note that some of these definitions are contradictory, others are merely orthogonal, and still others are special cases..." and [Weak Typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_typing): "...opposite of strong typing, and consequently (...) has as many different meanings..."

Comment: @Renesis: I'd call it "realism" :-) I have seen enough discussions about type systems to realize that half the people don't realize they are talking about completely different things and the other don't know what they are talking about *at all*. A couple of months ago, there was a discussion on the core development list of a language I won't name, about adding an optional type system to improve performance. That discussion went on for a week, involved dozens of people and hundreds of mails. Not *one* realized that an optional type system *by definition* can't improve performance. …

Comment: … The definition of Optional Typing is more or less "doesn't change the runtime behavior". The *whole point* of optimizations *is* to change the runtime behavior (usually to make code run faster, sometimes to make it use less memory). Ergo, an optional type system cannot be used for optimizations. It's really sad to see very smart people waste hours arguing about something without realizing that they simply forgot to agree upfront *what* they are arguing about.

Comment: +1 for cynism! You might add "strong typing=when the IDE knows the types of my variables (Intellisense etc.), weak typing=when it doesn't)"

Comment: The better-defined names for typing systems lack the implicit value judgement *weak* and *strong* have.

Comment: Gorgeous, entertaining, and accurate. The more I've learned about type systems, the more I've realized how long I suffered under the illusion that one language was different from another in ways it just wasn't at all. It's amazing just how much confusion this concept causes, and I really think it isn't necessary if only we accept that weak/strong isn't a real thing, so let's talk about something that actually is and maybe we'll learn something.

Comment: Is it me, or is this not really an answer? If you don't feel the question is clear, write a comment or help update the question. "Your question doesn't make sense because your terms are too vague" is not an answer.

Comment: @JörgWMittag: it seems obvious that when people discuss the time performance and say: *"doesn't change the runtime behavior"* they mean that the corresponding results won't change within reasonable bounds. It even can be reflected in the name of the type: `int_fast8_t`. Another example, adding `restrict` to some input pointer types may speed up corresponding functions without *necessarily* changing their results.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: No, that's not how it works. The thing is: if you have to annotate your code with types to make it run fast, then there will always be some boundary case where the code is just too slow without type annotations, and just fast enough *with* type annotations. However, if you have to add type annotations to get acceptable performance, then they are no longer optional! It's really important that an optional type system rejects non-type-safe programs and *that's it*. It doesn't do anything else.

Comment: Weak typing: Where I have to create the object and then use a debugger to figure out what the properties of that object are. /joke

Comment: what do you mean by "but whenever I have to solve the same problem in Bash and PowerShell, I am painfully reminded how wrong I was", do you say that powershell has proved that strong-types are very useful in the shell?

Comment: @santiagoarizti: Yes, *when done right*, as it is in PowerShell.

Comment: @threed Yes, this is an answer. It's not the question is hard to understand because it doesn't use the normal meanings of jargon. There are *too many* normal meanings in this case.

Comment: It's all about it being a refactor friendly language that does not involve search and replace. Such languages are also typically compile time safe and their usage is easily tracked through clear references/pointers. To think that people only know one language is the cause for this preference is ludicrous. There used to be plenty of fullstack developers back in the days. In general, you are able to more easily refactor statically typed languages which will lead you to better code in the long term.

Answer (score 30):

Remember there are two major concepts that are commonly confused:

#### Dynamic typing

> A programming language is said to be dynamically typed when the majority of its type checking is performed at run-time as opposed to at compile-time. In dynamic typing, values have types but variables do not; that is, a variable can refer to a value of any type.

The advantages here are often dismissed as just for "new" programmers, but can also be convenient for any programmer:

```
if (!(arr is Array)) arr = [arr]; // is, instanceof, .constructor ==, whatever
```

Less code in any case where you'd otherwise have to cast or assign a new value:

```
if (data is Array)) {
    i = data.length; // no i = ((Array)data).length or Array myArr=(Array)data;
}
```

#### Loose or weak typing

> Weak typing means that a language implicitly converts (or casts) types when used.

Benefits:

- **Pass any type value as a parameter to a function**. Useful for callbacks, flexible APIs, and makes for a simpler implementation of closures.
- **Implicit boolean evaluation**. Any type can be evaluated as a boolean.  This also has side benefits such as a part of an `||` can be used in assignment without conversion to boolean:

  ```
  var a = param || defaultValue;
  ```
- **Again, less code:**

  ```
  var num = 5;
  var str = "Hello";
  input.innerHTML = input.value = num;
  for (var i=0; i < input.value; i++) { ... }
  ```

  Even Java had to go partway, with the implicit call to `.toString()` when combining objects with a `String`; otherwise Java programmers would be cursing it all day long (log statements would be out of control).

---

<sup>Both definitions are from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system. It said it better than I could.</sup>

Comment: Dynamic typing is also beneficial where lots of code generation would be required in a statically-typed language. Compare the amount of code generation required for, say, Entity Framework in C# to ORM libraries in dynamically-typed languages (PHP, Python, etc). Though some may argue that the benefits in terms of IDE IntelliSense outweighs the cost of all that code generation...

Comment: Your comment "// no i = ((Array)data).length or Array myArr=(Array)data;" isn't really anything to do with dynamic typing, because the array-ness of data is provable at compile-time. A statically typed language could propagate knowledge obtained from instanceof.

Comment: @Peter Taylor, I suppose that's true in simple cases, do you know of any that do so? It does have to do with dynamic typing in that whether an `if` block is used or some other more complex (even runtime or dynamic) logic, the next line will be legal and safe from errors.

Comment: @Renesis, I don't, no. But the ML family of languages is statically typed and uses type inference so you very rarely have to explicitly state the type of a variable.

Comment: As a side-note, it's possible to write dynamically typed code in some statically typed languages, such as Java and C#, by making everything `object`. One important case where this is used is interfacing with a database without using an ORM.

Comment: @Peter Taylor it's true that the container will be able to contain different types but that's where the strong typing will still kill you, when you have to cast to do anything.

Comment: Java's `.toString()` (or .NET's `.ToString()`) is actually a good example of how you can solve that problem _without_ using dynamic typing, but by using a good inheritance hierarchy. But still, dynamic typing is a tool which is sometimes better at solving certain problems. It's all about choosing the right tool – sometimes it's static typing, and sometimes dynamic.

Comment: @Peter Taylor is correct. Many of the benefits of dynamic typing are available in languages with better static typing systems, like Haskell, Scala or even C# in some cases. I would say the major advantage of dynamic typing is dealing with things that are inherently typeless, like HTML DOM. Why write node["attr"] instead of node.attr? They are always resolved at runtime anyway.

Comment: @Allon Guralnek: Actually, I would consider them to be pretty *bad* examples. A much better example would be the `Show` typeclass in Haskell (which has essentially the same goal: providing human-readable text representations of values). There are actually implementations of it (or at least as close as you can get, given the limitations of their type systems) for both Java and C#.

Answer (score 9):

The main argument *for* weak typing is one of performance.  (this is to answer the OPs question as stated).  There's a lot of good discussion about dynamic vs. static, implicit vs. explicit. etc.

C is the most famous weakly typed language, and it does not perform any run time checking or compile time checking of the variables type.  In essence you can cast a `char *` to an `int *` and the language wouldn't care.  So why would you do this?

C programming is pretty close to the way you would do things with assembly, so there are times where you only care about an address.  It's not uncommon to cast or pass a `void *` reference for that very reason.  If you know how the memory is organized (again a C and assembly concern), you can do some pretty cool calculations based on the address in the `void *` to get at the information you need.  This can let you short-circuit the process you would have to go through in Java for instance.

While run-time type checking doesn't have an extraordinary bit of overhead, there are times when it is just enough to cause a critical section to be too slow.  I'm thinking mostly about embedded programming and real time systems in this case.

That said, in most cases having a strong type system that is either compile time checked or runtime checked helps more often than it hurts.

Comment: I don't see why a strongly-typed language can't compile as efficiently as C. But the compiler should be vastly more complex.

Comment: C++ is an example of one such language.  In C++ all type checking is done at compile time, and none are done at run time... UNLESS you have RTTI enabled.

Comment: Not sure I agree with this performance argument, but it *is* an interesting view.

Answer (score 3):

Weak typing is typically easier for newbies to grasp, for instance in things like excel,javascript and vbscript. You also trade some development speed for potential errors.

Good article on the subject: [Strong typing vs Strong testing](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-1-4302-0038-3_11)

Comment: I don't think there's a strong correspondence between weakly typed languages and newbie friendly languages. Ruby and python are strongly typed and generally considered newbie friendly. C is weakly typed and generally considered newbie hostile.

Comment: No, not the language in general, I was just talking about the typing

Comment: Dynamic and strongly typed are the newbie friendly combination. Although I have seen that when people move from a statically typed language to a dynamically typed one, they also get really confused. I've never seen someone who started with dynamically typed though since the schools end up teaching C or Java first most of the time.

Comment: Boy, did I have issues moving from strong & static typing language to weak & dynamic typing language. Not having to declare a variable type felt just wrong.

Comment: @Mchl: that doesn't have anything to do with either static/dynamic or strong/weak typing. Having to declare types is about explicit/implicit typing.

Comment: Might just as well be ;) So I moved also from explicitly to implicitly typed language. Correct me if I'm wrong Pascal is statically, strongly and explicitly typed, while PHP is dynamically, weakly and implicitly typed, aren't they?

Comment: @Basic Unless "dynamically/strongly" typed means something other than "dynamically typed and strongly typed" (which I don't see how it could), your second sentence directly contradicts your first.

Comment: Strong typing often requires a whole load of boilerplate code for things like mocking out dependencies for unit tests. I find I am more productive writing Javascript than C# where I have a whole load of interfaces to maintain; and if I forget to define a method my unit tests catch it. That said languages like Javascript and PHP give you plenty of rope to hang yourself if you're not disciplined. I disagree weak-typing is for 'newbies', losing the safety net of compile-time checking can be more challenging.