# Can a loosely typed language be considered true object oriented?

Tags: php, object-oriented, architecture, object-oriented-design, weak-typing

Can a loosely typed programming language like PHP be really considered object oriented?

I mean, the methods don't have returning types and method parameters has no declared type either.

Doesn't class design require methods to have a return type?
Don't methods signatures have specifically-typed parameters?

How can OOP techniques help you code in PHP if you always have to check the types of parameters received because the language doesn't enforce types?

Please, if I'm wrong, explain it to me.

**When you design things using UML, then code classes in PHP with no return-typed methods and no-type parameters... Is the code really compliant with the UML design?**

**You spend time designing your software architecture, then the compiler doesn't force the programmer to follow your design while coding, letting he/she assign any object variable to any other variable with no "type-mismatch" warning.**

Comment: I may be wrong, but don't dynamic languages such as Ruby or Python have their JIT compiler determine what type an object is at runtime? So while you may not explicitly *see* it's object oriented, when you run the program it actually is. `If I'm wrong, please let me know. :)`

Comment: @Serg You confuse language and implementation. Also, JIT compilation is a mere implementation detail, and one with no observable effect (I'm talking about semantics, not performance) to boot. But yes, any implementation of a dynamic language *has* to track the types of values *somehow*. Regardless of object orientation.

Comment: The term "loosely"-typed is not well defined. There are two distinct qualities of type systems: Strongly typed (e.g. Java, Python) vs. weakly typed (e.g. C) and statically typed (e.g. C, Java) vs. dynamically typed (e.g. Python, PHP). Usually anything dynamically typed has to also be strongly typed, though I am not sure PHP does not have some functions that would violate it, since it's bindings to the C library are quite thin and rough.

Comment: Follow-up: Having noticed the [Don't describe type systems as "weak".](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9929697/395760) in the other comment, "weak" and "strong" are not really well defined either. The "static" vs. "dynamic" is the main distinction that is well defined. By "weak" vs. "strong" I meant whether it allows casting in a way that may cause undefined behaviour at runtime (like casting number to pointer in C).

Comment: can dynamically typed language be truly OO - yes, can PHP be considered truly OO - no.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The classic attributes of OOP are: inheritance, polymorphism and encapsulation. No mention of strong typing.

I do not know PHP, but I have coded OOP Python and it feels just like OOP C#.

Comment: I agree. It's a classic logical fallacy: "C++, C# and Java are OO languages. C++, C# and Java have strict type checking. Therefore, OO languages require strict type checking".

Comment: Note that Alan Kay, who after all *invented* the term "Object-Oriented" and thus gets to decide what it means has this to say: "I invented the term object-oriented and I can tell you I did not have C++ in mind".

Answer (score 8):

> Doesn't class design need methods to have a return type?

Why?  You aren't modifying the code itself at runtime, so the method *has* a return type whether it's predeclared or not.  Just because it can't be enforced doesn't mean it doesn't exist — it can clearly be inferred from the code itself.

> Doesn't methods signatures have specifically-typed parameters ?

Again, there's nothing to say that the method can't simply be liberal in what it receives.  Get user by id? Sure, pass in a String or an integer.  How does that break *object-oriented-programming*?

> How can OOP techniques help you code in PHP if you have to always check the types of parameters received because the language doesn't enforce types ?

Here, based on the above arguments, I again fail to see why "extra checking", even if needed, renders OOP techniques powerless.

The loosely-typed languages that I am familiar with don't have [method overloading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_overloading), which is often used to make methods more flexible on input (while still using the same name), so I fail to see much difference from using one method and "extra checking".  A diligent developer can write the same method, with the same contract, stability and security in a loosely-typed language.

> When you design things using UML, then code classes in PHP with no return-typed methods and no-type parameters... Is the code really compliant with the UML design ?

Well this depends on your method itself, doesn't it?  What it actually does with the inputs and what it outputs?

### Typing still exists

The bottom line is, types still exist, they are just *loose* or *weak*<sup>1</sup>, and these systems can [even have certain advantages](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/38014/2314).

In fact, some IDEs like those by JetBrains (IntelliJ, PHPStorm) support all kinds of [type hinting using PHPDocs for PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1816641/jetbrains-webide-php-variable-type-hinting).  As I've used it, it provides almost all the convenient warnings, click-through, code-completion, etc. that an IDE for a strongly-typed can provide.

---

*1: Both "loose" and "weak" are just a poor grouping anyway; there are so many different type systems that these terms are likely to cause confusion.  See [Eric Lippert's informative perspective on this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9929697/395760) on Stack Overflow.*

---

#### Method doc and inline example

```
/**
 * @static
 * @param mixed $id
 * @return User
 */
public function getUserById($id) {
    ....
}

public function printUserName() {
    // code completion provided on getName method because of @return
    $name = $this->getUserById("5")->getName();

    // type hinting for arrays
    /** @var User[] $users */
    $users = array(new User());
}
```

#### Casting example

```
public function checkUser(User $user) {
    if ($user instanceof Administrator) {
        /** @var Administrator $admin  */
        $admin = $user;
        $admin->logAccess();
    }
}
```

Comment: [Don't describe type systems as "weak".](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9929697/395760)

Comment: @delnan Interesting link, thanks.  But, one mention and I get scolded?  I only mentioned it because even [Wikipedia's article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_typing) is titled *weak typing*. :(

Comment: @delnan By the way, if you follow my link you'll see it is to an answer of mine where I too tried to clear up some confusion in the term.

Comment: @delnan (Sorry for the multiple comments, was reading and digging up links) Lastly, I think Lippert's answer is food for thought but is generally of the vein "if we can't define every term to a perfect standard then conversation is futile" which I find a bit extreme.  I think the various ([1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_and_weak_typing), [2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system#Strong_and_weak_typing)) Wikipedia articles are a more fair and useful assessment for typical conversation.

Comment: The problem is (and the Wikipedia article illustrates), weak typing has a dozen incompatible meanings, and all are in common use. That makes the term meaningless. Even if *you* define it to mean a particular, unambiguous property of programming languages in mind, you have to add to every statement that your definition of weak typing is such and such, and at that point you may as well use that definition directly instead of risking someone replacing your definition with his. I am convinced that the term is 100% useless to harmful and therefore shouldn't be used **at all**.

Comment: @delnan Case in point: the OP said "loosely typed" and we generally know what is meant after a couple of mentions of which languages we're dealing with.  English is full of words or phrases that require context. There are enough similarities between Java and C# or JavaScript, Python, PHP to make some generalizations.  After all, I didn't expect my answer to hold up to research standards, I'm just trying to help a fellow programmer out.

Comment: I don't expect a Q&A site post to strictly define everything, and I don't mean to disrespect your answer (in fact I concur and think it's very well-written, +1). I'm just promoting, whenever I can, the idea of collectively abandoning a term which is far more likely to cause confusion. The asker of the question I linked to is not the first to be confused, and there has been more than one heated debate (and holy wars too) about which language is strongly typed or not. Just ask any militant Haskeller how "strong" C#'s type system is. Or ask around whether Python has strong or weak typing.

Comment: @delnan Again, thanks for the link.  I've integrated it into the answer because I think you are right: it's worth educating on this wherever possible.

Comment: That's the point. You have to check with instanceof because the language lets you pass anything in the paremeter. In strictly typed languages, the code doesn't compile if types doesn't match or can't be dinamically casted because the parameter passed is not a subclass of the type expected.

Comment: I don't think that really is the point, because that *checking* doesn't have anything to do with OOP.  You can still cause bad casting at runtime in a "strictly" typed language, anyway.

Answer (score 5):

The original object-oriented language where Alan Key introduced the concept was [Smalltalk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smalltalk). It is dynamically typed.

Actually Alan Key mentioned the classes and interfaces approach of C++ and Java is *not* what he had in mind when he invented object oriented programming. So the question should perhaps even be the other way, whether statically typed languages can be truly object oriented.

> I mean, the methods don't have returning types and method parameters has no declared type either.
>   Doesn't class design need methods to have a return type? Doesn't methods signatures have specifically-typed parameters?

No, they don't have specifically *typed* parameters. Their parameters and return values have to have specific set of methods, but they don't have to be specific types. In statically typed languages that is enforced by declaring an interface. In dynamically typed ones, you just document it.

> How can OOP techniques help you code in PHP if you have to always check the types of parameters received because the language doesn't enforce types?

You should never check types of parameters received. You should simply call methods on them. That's called "duck typing" (if it quacks like a duck and walks like a duck, I would call it a duck, or if it has methods like X, it will do for X). It's how things are usually done in smalltalk, perl, python, ruby etc. and as they should be done in PHP.

Comment: [Simula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simula) had already introduced the concepts in object oriented programming and was an influence on Smalltalk.

Comment: +1 for "don't check types, just call methods". well done, this allows a far better polymorphism than mere inheritance.

Answer (score 3):

> Doesn't class design need methods to have a return type?

Not really.

> Doesn't methods signatures have specifically-typed parameters ?

Sure. Just because the types aren't enforced by the compiler doesn't mean that there's not implied contract and semantics that the methods require/implement.

> How can OOP techniques help you code in PHP if you have to always check the types of parameters received because the language doesn't enforce types ?

By focusing on Object Oriented Programming. Again, how you organize the implied contracts of dynamic languages in your design is where OO comes into play.